# Как заставить телеграм бота работать со множеством пользователей?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

````
    def __init__(self, user_id):
        self.user_id = user_id


        @dp.message_handler()
        async def vin_reciever(message: types.Message):
            vins = message.text
            vin = vins.split()
            max = len(vin)
            print(max)

            options = Options()
            options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
            options.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)
            options.set_preference("browser.fullscreen.autohide", False)
            options.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
            options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
            browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
            browser.get(url)
            time.sleep(2)
            await bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text="Проверка начата")
            valid = 0
            n = 0

            while n != max:
                time.sleep(0.3)
                browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                     "/html/body/main/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/input").send_keys(
                    "")
                browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                     "/html/body/main/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/input").send_keys(
                    vin[n])
                browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                     "/html/body/main/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div/input").click()
                if len(browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "vin-check__card-items")) != 0:
                    print(vin[n])
                    await bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text=f"{vin[n]} валидный ")
                    valid = valid + 1
                    browser.save_screenshot(f"cin numver {n}.png")

                n += 1
                browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                     "/html/body/main/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/input").send_keys(
                    Keys.CONTROL, "BACKSPACE")
            if n == max:
                await bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text="Проверка закончена")
                browser.close()
                if valid == 0:
                    await bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text="Нет ни одного валидного вина")


async def on_start(_):
    print("Бот запущен")
@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    global user_id
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text="Привет, напиши /check чтобы начать проверку")

@dp.message_handler(commands=["check"])
async def start(message: types.Message):

    user_id = message.from_user.id
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text="Введите проверяемые номера")
    user = Cheker(user_id)
    user.__init__(user_id=user_id)```

Этот код должен обрабатывать сообщения от разных пользователей, но если он проверяет строки одного, то у всех других будет молчать, как только заканчивает проверять строки первого пользователя переходит к следующему (кто раньше нажал start) 
Как сделать так чтобы бот работал со всеми сразу?
````

Comment: У вас код выполняется асинхронно, т.к. есть `async`, но при этом используете не асихронные вещи типа `time.sleep(2)` и `selenium`. Асинхронные функции в рамках одного цикла обработки событий работают в одном потоке, а вещи, что описал ранее как вредные тормозят текущий поток, т.к. не являются асинхронными. Вам нужно или использовать не асихронного бота, а работающего на потоках, либо использовать асинхронные функции

Comment: Бот, работающий на потоках каждый запрос выполнял бы в отдельном потоке. Например, python-telegram-bot (например, pip install python-telegram-bot==13.7), но версии 13, т.к. с следующей мажорной версии тот перешел на асинхронность (думаю, т.к. она эффективнее, чем на потоках)